# Equation for a physic theory

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

There is a theory that state and explains why everything on Earth (or on a place with same force of gravity) falls at the exact same acceleration in vacuum. What's the name of that theory, who came up with it and how does the equations for it looks? And how does it work?

Comment: this does not make sense, though I did not downvote as I see you are fairly new here, also it seems in physics.

Comment: Have you looked up Galileo on Wikipedia? Although the _in vacuum_ part is unknown to me. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei#Falling_bodies, no actually rereading it, it seems that you know about gravity, so it does not make sense to me either

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure about your level of physics education so please ask if I've jumped too far in any of these steps.

What determines how something falls is the force acting upon it. The force is related to it's acceleration by Newtons famous law $f=ma$ where $f$ is the force, $m$ is the mass (how heavy it is) and $a$ is the acceleration (how fast its speed is changing).

The (classical) equation for the force of gravity is: $$f=\frac{GmM}{r^2}$$ where $G$ is a number that doesn't matter too much, $m$ is the mass of the object falling, $M$ is the mass of the object it is falling towards (so in this case $M$ is the mass of the earth) and $r$ is the distance between the two.

Setting these two $f$s equal to each other we can work out the acceleration of and object falling under gravity: $$ma = \frac{GmM}{r^2}$$ and we can divide both sides by $m$ to get: $$a = \frac{GM}{r^2}$$

So we see the *acceleration doesn't depend on $m$ (the mass of the object falling) at all!* $m$ simply doesn't appear in the equation for $a$.

By the way the $r$ in the formula above is the distance from the falling object to the *centre of the earth* (for reasons I'm not going to get into). As distances that things fall on earth are massively smaller than the distance from the surface to the centre its generally fine to treat the $r^2$ factor as constant and define $g=\frac{GM}{r^2}\approx 9.8\text{ms}^{-2}$. The equation then becomes:$$a=g=9.8\text{ms}^{-2}$$

Everything falling near the earth's surface (ignoring air resistance) falls at about $9.8\text{ms}^{-2}$.

Comment: It would be useful for the OP to also mention that for a free falling body not too far from the Earth's surface $F=mg$ and that $g = a = \frac{GM}{r^2}$.

Comment: @Gert Thanks. I've edited my answer a bit. Anything else you think could be improved?